# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 Error

Tags: python, json

I've just started learning Python. I got this error in the code I used. I would be glad if you help. Thanks

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
headers = {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Referer': 'http://www.wikipedia.org/',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.ebooks.com/en-tr/subjects/computers/?ResultOrder=Popularity/', headers=headers)

response.status_code

response.json() # the mistake is here
```

[View error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lp1TY.png)

Edit;
I found the solution. When I used the params parameter in the requests get function, the problem was resolved and I was able to output as jason without any problems.

```
    params = (
    ('subjectId', '13'),
    ('pageNumber', '1'),
    ('countryCode', 'DE'),
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: In your own words, when you make this request, why do you think you should get JSON data back? When you go to that URL in a web browser, do you see JSON?

Comment: I'm watching a training set. The instructor had done it this way

Comment: I found the solution. When I used the params parameter in the requests get function, the problem was resolved and I was able to output as jason without any problems.

Comment: Please, next time, search for the error you get online. This question comes up daily. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The response content is HTML, not JSON. You can view it with `response.content` or `response.text`.

Comment: No, I wanted to output it as json

Comment: I'm watching a training set. The instructor had done it this way

Comment: If you receive HTML from that API, what you want is irrelevant. Of course, it's some kind of error somewhere, but this answer still accurately explains why you get an error when trying to parse the HTML as JSON.